# ProgressView Overflowing UIView bounds

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview

I have a progressView (UIView) inside a UIView, and it over flows the bounds (using autolayout).

- When I set progress to 0.5 (50%), it covers the entire view
- When I set progress to 0.75 (75%), it over flows the UIView

I have even tried `sizeToFit()` and `clipToBounds()`. Neither have solved the problem. When I println the width of the frame, it is the original value in Storyboard, which is too big when rendered on the device.

```
class ProgressView: UIView {
    var progress: CGFloat! = 0.75
    var filledView: UIView!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        filledView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: frame.height))
        filledView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(filledView)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        filledView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: frame.height))
        filledView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        addSubview(filledView)
    }

    func setProgress(var progress: CGFloat) {
        progress = min(max(progress, 0), 1) // Between 0 and 1
        self.progress = progress
        println(self.frame.width)
        filledView.frame.size.width = self.frame.width * progress
        filledView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hve you tried modifying the height of a native progress view with CGAffineTransformMakeScale?

Comment: @JuandelaTorre i have not. what does `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` affect?

Comment: As the name implies, it affects the scale of the transform property, I suggested CGAffineTransformMakeScale because I saw you need to have a progress bar that is thicker than the native one. I'm pretty sure If you use the native progress view you won't have those issues of the filling part having the wrong size, not to mention all the logic of a progress bar it's already there, even animations.

Comment: @JuandelaTorre this helped a lot. i reverted my `uiview` to an actual `progressView`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the progress with:

```
self.progress = progress
```

It should animate by itself.
No need to change any frames in there.

Comment: yes, i actually called the function in another class to set the progress. i just added the progress in the code above to make it simpler. `self.view1.setProgress(0.50)` however, the problem is not the progress not showing. it is that the progress overflows the uiview.

Comment: Yes, remove "filledView.frame.size.width = self.frame.width * progress"

Comment: i gave it a try and it the  progressview is empty